# React Hooks mark checkbox in selected div, unmark when div removed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The issue is - when the div is selected and added to the list, the checkbox needs to be marked(ticked) and stay marked until the div is unselected.

"Click on Any of the 3 div's within the blue border to add it to the 'selected' area.
The checkbox needs to be marked with a tick when the div is selected and
the tick needs to be removed when the div has been unselected by pressing
the 'x,'"

sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-thursday-yjwxm?file=/src/App.js:620-880

Thanks in advance

````
export const App = () => {
  const [selectedConsole, setSelectedConsole] = useState([]);
  const [console, setConsole] = useState([]);

  const dataList = [
    {
      id: "001",
      name: "Atari",
      description: "Click here to add to list"
    },
    {
      id: "002",
      name: "Sega",
      description: "Click here to add to list"
    },
    {
      id: "003",
      name: "Nintendo",
      description: "Click here to add to list"
    }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setConsole(dataList ?? []);
  }, [setConsole]);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex flex-row border-1 border-gray-1 mt-4 h-466 w-553">
        <div className="h-466 w-303  overflow-auto ">
          {console &&
            console.map((item, index) => (
              <div
                key={`${""}-${index}`}
                className="text-sm2 text-blue-1 cursor-pointer border border-blue"
                onClick={() => {
                  !selectedConsole.includes(item) &&
                    setSelectedConsole((oldValue) => [...oldValue, item]);
                }}
              >
                <div className="flex flex-row relative w-60">
                  <div className="bg-white border-2 rounded border-blue-0 w-4 h-4 flex flex-shrink-0 mt-5 mr-1 focus-within:border-blue-0">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="opacity-0 absolute verification-checkbox"
                    />
                    <svg
                      className="fill-current hidden w-4 h-4 text-blue-3 pointer-events-none"
                      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                    >
                      <path d="M0 11l2-2 5 5L18 3l2 2L7 18z" />
                    </svg>
                  </div>
                  <div className="flex flex-col ml-2">
                    {item.name}
                    <div className="">{item.description}</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col h-300 w-248">
          <div className="flex row mt-2 w-62 pl-2 border-b border-gray-1 mb-3">
            <div className="">
              <span className="text-center inline-block w-3">
                {selectedConsole.length}
              </span>
              <span>selected</span>
            </div>
            <div
              className="pl-10 cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedConsole([]);
              }}
            >
              Unselect all
            </div>
          </div>
          {selectedConsole &&
            selectedConsole.map((format) => (
              <div
                className="flex flex-row justify-between text-blue-3 -ml-2 text-sm4 font-semibold rounded-lg px-4 p-0.5 w-248"
                key={format.id}
              >
                <div className="">{format.name}</div>
                <div
                  className="ml-3 font-bold cursor-pointer text-blue-3"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedConsole(
                      selectedConsole.filter((f) => f.name !== format.name)
                    );
                  }}
                >
                  X
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple change you could make is to add the `checked` property to your `<input />` element and drive that based on whether the current `item` is in your `console` array:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  className="absolute verification-checkbox"
  checked={selectedConsole.includes(item)}
/>
```

Note that I have also removed the `opacity-0` class as this hides the checkmark on the checkbox when it is checked.

A more efficient approach would be to add a `checked` key to your `item` objects, and then drive the `checked` value off of that instead of searching the array each time.

Comment: I Also added readOnly, It works.  <input
                      type="checkbox"
                        className="absolute verification-checkbox"
                      checked={selectedFormats.includes(item)}
                      readOnly
                    />

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way based on the example that you provided is as in the snippet below.

```
{selectedConsole.includes(item) && (
  <svg
    className="fill-current hidden w-4 h-4 text-blue-3 pointer-events-none"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
  >
    <path d="M0 11l2-2 5 5L18 3l2 2L7 18z" />
  </svg>
)}
```

As you are storing the state of item not in the checkbox, and you cannot remove the item with checkbox, but by clicking on `x`, I would even recommend to replace the checkbox part with button that changes it icon as is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `checked` property to `console` items and when `onClick`
change all array like this:

```
onClick={() => {
    !selectedConsole.includes(item) &&
    setSelectedConsole((oldValue) => [...oldValue, item]);
    const updatedConsole = console.map((element) => {
        if (item.id === element.id) {
            element.checked = true;
           }
        return element;
    });
    setConsole(updatedConsole);
}}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-filter-thursday-forked-3bmhn?file=/src/App.js